# Could someone explain me a haskell's function

Tags: haskell, fold

I found a solution to my exercise on the internet but I'm not sure what is it. The result is correct though.

```
foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) []
```

Could someone explain me exactly the steps of that function please? 
This should multiply all the elements of the list by 10.

Thank you

Comment: If you wanted to multiply every element list by 10, why not `map (*10)`?

Comment: The instructions says I can't use it.

Comment: Using only lambda expressions and foldr (i.e not map or filter) write a function that multiplies each element of a list by 10.

Comment: Link to the source of the problem. What you have is not a complete problem statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foldr` function can be defined as following:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f z []     = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

It takes a list of values of type `a` and a single value of type `b` – the accumulator. It takes items from the list, combines them with the accumulator and returns the final value. In your case, `a` is some number and `b` is in fact also a list of numbers. The complete type of your function is `Num a => [a] -> [a]`.

Consider application of your function to a list `[1,2,3]`:

```
foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [1,2,3] ~~>
(\n acc -> (n*10):acc) 1 (foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [2,3]) ~~>
(1*10) : foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [2,3] ~~>
10 : foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [2,3] ~~>
10 : (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) 2 (foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [3]) ~~>
10 : (2*10) : foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [3]
10 : 20 : foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [3] ~~>
10 : 20 : (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) 3 (foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] []) ~~>
10 : 20 : (3*10) : foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [] ~~>
10 : 20 : 30 : foldr (\n acc -> (n*10):acc) [] [] ~~>
10 : 20 : 30 : []
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not allowed to use `map` because this is homework, then you're probably not allowed to use `foldr` either. And using `foldr` to multiply every element in a list by 10 would be a rather silly way to do it (except as a learning exercise). As a general rule:

- If you want to do something to every element in a list, and get a *list* as the result, then you probably want some sort of *map* function.
- If you want to do something to every element in a list, and get a *single value* as the result, then you probably want one of the *fold* functions.

So let's write our own function. The function will take a list of numbers, and return a list. If you want to work with `Int`s, then:

```
myFunction :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

(Better yet, instead of hard-coding in 10, you could let that be an input parameter. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.)

We could use recursion to implement this function. When using recursion, start by asking yourself "what is the base (simplest) case". Well, that would be an empty list. If we get a list, there's nothing to do, so we just return the empty list.

```
myFunction [] = []
```

Now, what if our list is non-empty? Well, we can multiply the first element by 10, and concatenate that with the result of running `myFunction` on the rest of the list.

```
myFunction (x:xs) = x*10 : myFunction xs
```